# Request permissions errors

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions

I'm trying to make a map activity. In this map activity I want to show a "current location" button, so to make this appear I need to request for location permissions.

For some reasons, all the request permissions that I'm trying to request aren't showing up.

The request window isn't even showing up. What can be the problem?

This is my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private static final String FIREBASE_URL="https://****.firebaseio.com/";
private Firebase firebaseRef;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private GoogleMap mMap;
SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
boolean bPermissionGranted;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);




setUpMapIfNeeded();

 }

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
if (mMap == null) {
    // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    if (mMap != null) {


        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(32.065483, 34.824550));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);
        mMap.moveCamera(center);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

    }
}
}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public void checkLocationPermission() {
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            showMessageOKCancel("You need to accept location permissions for using these services!,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "came here 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        }
                        }
                    });
            return;
        }

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "came here 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;

    }
    else
    {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "came here 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



 }

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message,    DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this)
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        .create()
        .show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                   String permissions[], int[] grantResults)     {
switch (requestCode) {
    case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // permission was granted, yay!
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            // permission denied, boo! Disable the
            // functionality that depends on this permission.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return;
    }

}
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

mMap=googleMap;

mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

checkLocationPermission();


}
```

Do I need to write something in the manifest except of these line?:

In my logcat I've found this:

`E/linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/22') failed: Permission denied [fd=22]`

`E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/com.tranzmate/app_dx/v1/Generated_-470173342.dex". Will use given name.`

And this also appeard:

`GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
04-11 00:18:20.228 15674-15674/? E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
04-11 00:18:20.254 15674-15692/? E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled`

Maybe it is something in the gradle file?

Or maybe it is something in the SDK that I need to install?

Comment: @BobMalooga I know, because of it, before I use the bew permission request system, I check for the Android version. If it is lower than 6.0, It will use the older way.

Comment: @DanielNugent if I remove this line the app crashes. Please look at the log lines I've added above.

Answer (score 0):

must check in your Manifest file , where you call this permission no add

> noHistory = true